# Syntax error in aggregate argument: Expecting a single column argument with possible 'Child' qualifier

Tags: c#

```
DataTable distinctTable = dTable.DefaultView.ToTable(true,"ITEM_NO","ITEM_STOCK");
DataTable dtSummerized = new DataTable("SummerizedResult");

dtSummerized.Columns.Add("ITEM_NO",typeof(string));
dtSummerized.Columns.Add("ITEM_STOCK",typeof(double));

int count=0;

foreach(DataRow dRow in distinctTable.Rows)
{
  count++;
  //string itemNo = Convert.ToString(dRow[0]);
  double TotalItem = Convert.ToDouble(dRow[1]);

  string TotalStock = dTable.Compute("sum(" + TotalItem + ")", "ITEM_NO=" + dRow["ITEM_NO"].ToString()).ToString();
  dtSummerized.Rows.Add(count,dRow["ITEM_NO"],TotalStock);
}
```

Error Message: Syntax error in aggregate argument: Expecting a single column argument with possible 'Child' qualifier.

Do anyone can help me out?

Thanks.

Comment: error is in foreach loop @string TotalStock = Convert.ToString(dTable.Compute("sum(" + TotalItem + ")", "ITEM_NO=" + Convert.ToString(dRow["ITEM_NO"])));

Answer (score 23):

You might try this:

```
dTable.Compute("sum([" + TotalItem + "])","");
```

I.e enclose your column name in square brackets [ ]

The idea is from [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vblanguage/thread/8627a743-de02-44b2-a926-c9b304a8af13).

Answer (score 3):

The problem is exactly about your DataType of the column. If you have a row with dynamically added columns without DataType like that (it may be a result of a manual calculation or cross-tab query-like)

```
myTable.Columns.Add("AddedColumn");
```

You will probably face with the column conversion issue.
Instead, If you change your add method with pointing DataType like below

```
myTable.Columns.Add("AddedColumn", typeof(System.Int32));
```

It will work I think. It's what I experienced & fixed before...

Answer (score 0):

You want to write:

```
dTable.Compute("sum(CONVERT(ITEM_STOCK, 'System.Double'))",
               "ITEM_NO='" + dRow["ITEM_NO"].ToString() + "'")
```

instead of:

```
dTable.Compute("sum(" + TotalItem + ")", "ITEM_NO="...
```

because it will translate to `dTable.Compute("sum(value_of_TotalItem), "ITEM_NO="...`, `value_of_TotalItem` is a double and is not a column name.

See [`DataTable.Compute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.compute.aspx)

### UPDATE:

try this:

```
DataTable distinctTable = dTable.Clone();
dTable.Columns.Add("ITEM_STOCK_D", typeof(Decimal),
                   "CONVERT(ITEM_STOCK, 'System.Decimal')");
foreach (DataRow dRow in dTable.Rows)
{
    String itemNo = dRow["ITEM_NO"].ToString();
    if(distinctTable.Select(String.Format("ITEM_NO = '{0}'",itemNo)).Length == 0)
    {
        double totalStock = Convert.ToDouble(dTable.Compute("SUM(ITEM_STOCK_D)",
                                     String.Format("ITEM_NO = '{0}'", itemNo))); 
        distinctTable.Rows.Add(itemNo, totalStock.ToString());
    }
}
dTable.Columns.Remove("ITEM_STOCK_D");
```

Comment: Hi manji - double TotalStock = (double)dTable.Compute("sum(ITEM_STOCK)", "ITEM_NO =" + dRow["ITEM_NO"].ToString());
                dtSummerized.Rows.Add(count,dRow["ITEM_NO"],TotalStock);//I am getting error message as invalid usage of sum() and type of string.

Comment: The type of the column `Item_NO` is `string` so you have to put it's value between simple quotes: `, "ITEM_NO='" + dRow["ITEM_NO"].ToString() + "'")`

Comment: @manji - Sorry for bothering you but it's giving me same error invalid usage of aggregate function Sum() and type of string. I had try to solve but couldn't figure it out. 

 foreach(DataRow dRow in distinctTable.Rows)

            {

                count++;



                double TotalStock = (double)dTable.Compute("SUM(ITEM_STOCK)", "ITEM_NO='" + dRow["ITEM_NO"].ToString() + "'");

                dtSummerized.Rows.Add(count,dRow["ITEM_NO"],TotalStock);



            }

can you help me just one more time .

Comment: Ok, the code you posted  is not very clear, I was looking at `dtSummerized` but in fact you're applying `sum` to `distinctTable` and I assume that `ITEM_STOCK` in `distinctTable` are numbers but stored in a column of type string. If this is the case replace `sum(ITEM_STOCK)` by `sum(CONVERT(ITEM_STOCK, 'System.Double'))`

Comment: If this is not working, you can add a new computed column to `distinctTable` (befor the loop) containing converted values of `ITEM_STOCK`: `distinctTable.Columns.Add("ITEM_STOCK_D", typeof(Double), "Convert(ITEM_STOCK,'System.Double')")` then use this new column `...Compute("sum(ITEM_STOCK_D)...`

Comment: If this is also is not working, the best is to refactor your code to create datatable (distinctTable) columns with the right data type: `ITEM_STOCK:double/decimal`, `...` and everything will become easier

Comment: DataTable distinctTable = dTable.Clone();

            foreach (DataRow dRow in dTable.Rows)
            {
                String itemNo = dRow["ITEM_NO"].ToString();
                
                
                if (distinctTable.Select(String.Format("ITEM_NO = '{0}'", itemNo)).GetLength(0) == 0)
                {
                    double totalStock = Convert.ToDouble(dTable.Compute("SUM(ITEM_STOCK:double/decimal)", String.Format("ITEM_NO = '{0}'", itemNo)));
                    distinctTable.Rows.Add(itemNo,totalStock);
                }
            }

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was with my query itself.

My query returned difference of two columns. Like, `query="Select A,B,A-B from Table"` and I was performing sum on datatable using compute function as `dt.Compute("Sum(A-B)","")`.

So, datatable was unable to compute the sum of `A-B` column. I gave the difference column alias as `query="Select A,B,(A-B) as AB from Table"`
and `dt.Compute("Sum(AB)","")`.

Thus, resolved the error.