# Error while taking SUM() of column in datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
DataTable dtStock = new DataTable();
DataColumn dcTotalCases = new DataColumn("TotalCases");
dcTotalCases.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32");
dcTotalCases.ReadOnly = false;
dtStock.Columns.Add(dcTotalCases);
```

Method 1

```
int sum = Convert.ToInt32(dtStock.Compute("Sum([TotalCases]) ", "[TotalCases] <> ''"));
```

When I use this method, I get an error

> Invalid usage of aggregate function Sum() and Type: String.

Method 2

```
int sum = Convert.ToInt32(dtStock.Compute("SUM(Convert([TotalCases], 'System.Int32'))", "");
```

When I use this method, I get an error

> Syntax error in aggregate argument: Expecting a single column argument
>   with possible 'Child' qualifier.

Please help me...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Syntax error in aggregate argument: Expecting a single column argument with possible 'Child' qualifier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5637355/syntax-error-in-aggregate-argument-expecting-a-single-column-argument-with-poss)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe method #1 should work - just **don't compare** your `INT` column to an empty string!!

So use something like this:

```
int sum = Convert.ToInt32(dtStock.Compute("Sum(TotalCases)", "[TotalCases] > 0"));
```

or

```
int sum = Convert.ToInt32(dtStock.Compute("Sum(TotalCases)", "[TotalCases] IS NOT NULL"));
```

or whatever you need - just don't use `[TotalCases] <> ''` since that compares an `INT` to an empty string - and that's not going to work!

Comment: First option does not work Compute take two arguments.So i tried this way "int sum = Convert.ToInt32(dtStock.Compute("Sum([TotalCases]) ",""));".Still getting same error..Invalid usage of aggregate function Sum() and Type: String.

Comment: When i am trying this option "sum = Convert.ToInt32(dtStock.Compute("Sum([TotalCases]) ", "[TotalCases] > 0"));" i getting this error..."Cannot perform '>' operation on System.String and System.Int32."

Comment: When i am trying second option you provided,now this error "Invalid usage of aggregate function Sum() and Type: String."

Comment: @JobyKurian: you had an extra space after the `Sum(TotalCases)` in your sample - remove that unnecessary space, and both my lines of code will work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I have a Datatable which i have not specified datatype for any column. All the values in the column are integer type. when i user the above sum() i am getting the error. `Invalid usage of aggregate function Sum() and Type: String.` But when i specify the datatype for the column its working correctly.