# Expecting a single column argument with possible 'Child' qualifier

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

This is my code

```
public void loadNumberOfAgents() 
{
    string vmpstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["vmpMMProDat"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection vmpsqlcon = new SqlConnection(vmpstring);
    SqlCommand vmpCmd = new SqlCommand("SupGetAgentsWithInteractions", vmpsqlcon);

    SqlDataAdapter DAvmp = new SqlDataAdapter(vmpCmd);
    DataSet DSvmp = new DataSet();
    DSvmp.Clear();
    DAvmp.Fill(DSvmp);

    DataTable table;
    table = DSvmp.Tables[0];
    int numberOfAgents;
    Int32.TryParse(table.Compute("Count(*)", "").ToString(), out numberOfAgents);
}
```

I got this exception

> Syntax error in aggregate argument: Expecting a single column argument with possible 'Child' qualifier.

on the last line of my code.

When I execute the stored procedure in SQL Server 2005, I got this:

[image]

Comment: In the sql server window can you check what messages are you getting in the Messages tab?

Comment: You're lacking a `vmpCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure`; insert this before your execute your command. You need to tell your `SqlCommand` that you're using a **stored procedure** (vs. the default of inline SQL statements)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Syntax error in aggregate argument: Expecting a single column argument with possible 'Child' qualifier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5637355/syntax-error-in-aggregate-argument-expecting-a-single-column-argument-with-poss)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `*` in aggregate in `Compute` expression. Use the column name from your `DataTable`.